# Convert 3D Point To 2D Point

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, 2d

[image: Question]

What I am doing is displaying the same 2D texture map on the screen as the model in the scene.
And fit the model perfectly on the screen.
as the picture shows
The red dot is the center of Bounds.
The blue dot is the center of the 2D texture image.

Since 3D has depth, the center point of the 3D model is applied to the 2D image. 2D images will deviate from a certain position and cannot be connected together.

Edit
Finally I found the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54730680/9075835).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? This question does not yet contain a question.

Comment: Sorry. I added the content of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check Camera.WorldToScreenPoint method, if you wanna get 2D screen position, as I understood.

Comment: After trying it. This is not the effect I want.

Comment: Ok. After your editting I got what you want. 
Check this one: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html