# Is there a way to find all the edges of a 3D shape given its vertices?

Tags: java, linear-algebra, shapes

I have a list of vertices of a simple 3D shape like a pyramid, a cube or a dodecahedron, is there an algorithm to find all the connections between the "outer vertices" that make up a face?
Face being the regular 2d shape (square for a cube, triagles for a pyramid...)

for example, once projected a pyramid to 2D I have a matrix of 8 coordinates x,y for each vertice: `int[] coords = new int [8][2]` and came up with this way of calculating them

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    for(int a = 1; a<=4; a++){
        if(i+a!=3){
            if(a>i){
                edges.add(new Line( coords[i][0] * GROWTH + displacement ,
                                    coords[i][1] * GROWTH + displacement,
                                    coords[a][0] * GROWTH + displacement,
                                    coords[a][1] * GROWTH + displacement));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

This only works with pyramids, I wonder if there's a way of calculating all the edges of a given [n][2] set of coordinates representing a projected 3D shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Faces from a set of vertices

If you have a list of edges you can apply [the graph algorithm for faces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185666/find-all-faces-in-a-graph-from-list-of-edges), but I tried to guess a little.

If your shape is convex you can [find the convex hull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416861/how-to-find-convex-hull-in-a-3-dimensional-space) of the vertices.

If your shape is not convex, and your mesh is "fine" enough

You can push the edges iterate over the list of `V * (V - 1) / 2` pairs of vertices ordered by increasing distance; you add the vertex to the mesh if (1) it does not create a new face or (2) none of the edges used in the newly created faces will be in the contour of more than two faces.

#### Edges for a sphere

There is no unique answer to your question, check [Four ways to crate a mesh for a sphere](https://medium.com/@oscarsc/four-ways-to-create-a-mesh-for-a-sphere-d7956b825db4)

Here I translate the first approach, that is similar to geographical coordinates, based on latitude and longitude.

```java
for(int i = 0; i<num_parallels; i++){
    for(int a = 1; a<=4; num_meridians++){
        double y1 = PI * i / num_parallels;
        double y2 = l1 + PI / num_parallels;
        double x1 = 2.0 * PI * i / num_meridians;
        double x2 = x1 + 2.0 * PI / num_meridians;
        add_sphere_line(x1, y1, x1, y2); // a parallel
        add_sphere_line(x1, y1, x2, y1); // a meridian
   }
}
```

The function to add a sphere line

```
void add_sphere_line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
  add_3d_line(
   // starting point in 3D coordinates
   Math.cos(x1) * Math.sin(y1), Math.cos(y1), Math.sin(x1) * Math.sin(y1),
   // end point in 3D coordinates
   Math.cos(x2) * Math.sin(y2), Math.cos(y2), Math.sin(x2) * Math.sin(y2)
  );
}
```

Since you mention you projected the pyramid to 2D I imagine you can workout the projection of these arbitrary lines to 2D as well.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure this is what I was searching, with this method  there will be a bunch of squares if I understood this right

Comment: Sorry reading again I see that I was mislead when I first read it. I edited the question pointing three guesses for what you want.